# Create Gmail label without "show in IMAP" option

Tags: google-apps-script

I want create labels via google script(executed in my drive folder). This new labels must be not flaged as "show in IMAP".

I don't found how do this in the API documentation.

Acttualy I'm using "`GmailApp.createLabel(label)`".
But don't have parameters or methods for change this flag

Any idea how to do it?

Thanks.

-- EDITED  for more info --

Following the documentation of this urls:
1)https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#createLabel(String)
2)https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/labels/create

Using any of this cases i can create new tags without problems, but none of the two apis, allows us to set the flag "show in IMAP" to false.

This flag is visible via gmail->Configuration->labels. Is a checkbox in the options of each label.

I Want change this flag using google script but i don't found how can i do this.

example used for the apps-script documentation:

---

```
var label = "Example Label";
var gmailLabel = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(label) ? 
                  GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(label) : GmailApp.createLabel(label);
```

---

---

example used for  api v1/reference/users/labels/create

```
-- -------
var request = gapi.client.gmail.users.labels.create({
    'userId': userId,
    'label': {
      'name': "Example Label"
    }
  });
```

---

In the first case, we only can set the label name, in the second case we can define more parameters.
(labelListVisibility,messageListVisibility,name, color.backgroundColor , color.textColor).
None of they are for disable "show in IMAP".

Comment: Show more information. What you've tried, screenshots of what you get and what you're trying to get, etc.

Comment: Thanks tehhowch, I edited the original question.

Comment: I'm not aware of this functionality at the present time either, unfortunately. You could file a request on their [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues) but ... Google does what Google wants.

Comment: Thanks for all tehhowch.